# Cannot declare variable 'x' to be of abstract type 'Queue<int>'

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism, pure-virtual

I am building a Queue class that is inherited from an abstract class and when I was testing my constructor i kept falling on this error and I can't understand why:

"Cannot declare variable 'x' to be of abstract type 'Queue'"

"because the following virtual functions are pure within 'Queue' "

"void Abstractclass::pop()    [Elem=int]"

MAIN.CPP:

```
#include "abstractclass.h"
#include "queue.h"
#include "stack.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

Queue<int> x(10);


getch();

return 0;
}
```

ABSTRACTCLASS.H:

```
#ifndef ABSTRACTCLASS_H
#define ABSTRACTCLASS_H
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class Elem>
class Abstractclass
{
    public:
    Abstractclass();
    virtual ~Abstractclass();
    virtual void pop()=0;
};

#endif // ABSTRACTCLASS_H
```

QUEUE.H:

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H
#include "abstractclass.h"

template <class Elem>
class Queue: public Abstractclass <Elem>
{
    public:
        Queue(int);
       ~Queue();
        void Pop(const Elem &item);
    private:
        Elem *data;
        const int maxsize;
        int firstdata;
        int lastdata;
        int queuesize;
};

#endif // QUEUE_H
```

Comment: `void pop()` is not the same as `void Pop(const Elem &item)`. You need to implement `void pop()` in the derived class.

Comment: OT: What should `void Pop(const Elem &item);` do? That doesn't look correct for my understanding of a queue....

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Hi, thank you very much for you answer.

Now that I corrected this i get a

 "undefined reference to 'Queue<int>::Queue(int)"  error

do you know the reason ??

Comment: Because you didn't define that constructor. Get a good book on C++ and start from the basics.

Comment: @JonathanWakely allright Mr.Pretentious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In class Queue:

```
virtual void pop( );
```

And spell it pop, not Pop, will fix it. c++ is case sensitive.

I'm not sure why your error message, (different compiler?), but it should have been:

```
  error: 'void Abstractclass<Elem>::pop(void)': is abstract
```

I take it your linker says: 'undefined reference to...' So the fix compiles fine but you have no definitions to link to, like:

```
Abstractclass() { }
virtual ~Abstractclass() { }
```

and:

```
Queue (int)
    :maxsize( 2 )
{ }
~Queue() { }
virtual void pop( ) { }
```

And note you have to initialize maxsize as it is declared constant

( I should have posted this here origanaly as I can't mark down comments)

Comment: Thank you !! I managed to fix the problem.
Now, for a reason i get these errors:


temp\main.cpp|11|undefined reference to `Queue<int>::Queue(int)'|

temp\main.cpp|16|undefined reference to `Queue<int>::~Queue()'|

||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 3 second(s)) ===|

Do you know why by any chance ??

Comment: I take it your linker says: 'undefined reference to...' So the fix compiles fine but you have no definitions to link to, like:

Comment: I take it your linker says: 'undefined reference to...' So the fix compiles fine but you have no definitions to link to, like:
 Abstractclass() { }
 virtual ~Abstractclass() { }
 Queue (int)
  :maxsize( 2 )
  //:Abstractclass< Elem >( )
 { }
 ~Queue() { }
 virtual void pop( ) { }

And note you have to initialize maxsize as it is declared constant